Отобразить структурированный sitemap
Пытаюсь сразу сделать вывод xml разметки из файла php. Данные файла sitemap
$St  ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo $st;

Но при просмотре в бразере, отображаемый код читается как за html
htmlspecialchars

Не помогает...
Как сделать чтобы структурированные данные файла sitemap, отображались так же из php как при открытии файла Sitemap.xml...

Надо попробовать установить нужный заголовок файла:
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";

